# How to know snapshot view is more efficient?

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, transition, snapshot

I use `snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)` when working with custom animated transitions because according to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview), it's more efficient.

Also, in some edge cases, snapshotting views will fix problems of transitioning frames incorrectly...

However, for simple transitions, I don't know how better it is compare to using fromView and toView directly. So how to measure the efficiency of it?

Comment: You can use `instruments`

Answer (score 1):

However i don't know what are you comparing this to, or what is

> More efficient

To you.

Altho **Instruments** is powerful tool provided by apple to Diagnose and solve performance issues, by clicking `cmd + i` you rebuild your application and start instruments automatically then you can choose one of the listed issues or diagnose tools to test.

In your case i assume you care about **FPS (Frames Per Second)**, `CoreAnimation`, and some general memory performance.

I suggest start looking into this tool under the `Core Animation or Time profiler`

- Time Profiler: used to measure CPU usage, broken down by
  method/function.
- Core Animation: used to debug all kinds of Core
  Animation performance issues.

Read more about instruments in [this](https://medium.com/@zhenya.peteliev/diagnose-and-solve-performance-problem-with-xcode-instruments-5c25c27f21d5) great article

Comment: This article shows an example of why using snapshotView is helpful https://www.appcoda.com/view-animation-in-swift/

Comment: FPS is not what I mean, and I did use instrument. Unfortunately, it does not help. I try to use it to compare a custom transition animation from 1 view to the other (view a lot of subviews to generate), but it does not show any clear differences or benefits of using snapshotView.